# Json not returning attribute in it

Tags: android, json, listview, arraylist

i have to extract name as well as stream url from the jason.i am getting the jason but i am not able to get stream url.Although there is no problem in getting channel names.

```
public class listviewData extends Activity{

ListView listview;
ArrayList<String> gidarrayobtained;
ArrayList<String> channellist;
ArrayList<String> urlarray;
JSONArray station_list = null; 
EditText inputsearch;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

//ArrayList<String> list;
    public void onCreate(Bundle saved)
{
    super.onCreate(saved);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);
    inputsearch=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputsearch);
    listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    Intent in=getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> b=in.getStringArrayListExtra("list");
    gidarrayobtained=in.getStringArrayListExtra("gidarray");
    //System.out.println("nav array"+gidarrayobtained);

    //list=b.getStringArrayList("list");
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,b);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */

    inputsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
        {
            // When user changed the Text
            listviewData.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id)
    {

        ongenreclick(position); 
        //System.out.println("we got"+position);

    }
    });

}

public void ongenreclick(int pos)
{

    String gid=gidarrayobtained.get(pos);
    //System.out.println("here comes the"+gid);
    String num="&num=1000";
    String finalchannellisturl="http://streamfinder.com/api/index.php?api_codekey=UopOfoCpfTujFxwqk5gjyHb38nSY1f45EMPD2gzwKQBe81buHw2e5ZA2i2eJNXk7GiT1chjgCbspwzpefcb3vy5o6uRpjTBbURUZqWdAedw7tyX2yTFXFAy67Pw5NSrG&return_data_format=json&do=genre_search"+"&gid="+gid;
    String premiumapigenre=finalchannellisturl+num;
    System.out.println(premiumapigenre);
    Uri uri=Uri.parse(premiumapigenre);

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(uri.toString());
    System.out.println("we are getting the channels"+json);

    //String str=json.toString();
    //int a=str.indexOf("name");

    try

    {
        //System.out.println("Names of  the channels are"+json.getJSONObject("station_list").getJSONObject("10000").get("name"));
        //System.out.println("Finally we got the array"+json.getJSONObject("station_list").getJSONObject("1").getJSONObject("streams").get("stream_url"));
        System.out.println("Finally we got the diffrent array"+json.getJSONObject("station_list").getJSONObject("1").getJSONObject("streams").get("stream_format_string").toString());
        channellist=new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
        {
            try
            {
                channellist.add(json.getJSONObject("station_list").getJSONObject(""+i).get("name").toString());

                urlarray=new ArrayList<String>();
                String st[]=json.toString().split("stream_url");
                for(int j=0;i<st.length;i++)
                    System.out.println("url done by me"+st[j]);
                urlarray.add(json.getJSONObject("station_list").getJSONObject(""+i).getJSONObject("streams").get("stream_url").toString());
                System.out.println("Finally we got the array"+json.getJSONObject("station_list").getJSONObject("1").getJSONObject("streams").get("stream_url"));

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }

        System.out.println("urlarray is"+urlarray.size());
        Intent intent=new Intent(listviewData.this,channelsOfGenres.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("channellist",channellist);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("urlarray",urlarray);
        listviewData.this.finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    catch(JSONException e1)

    {
        System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
    }

}
}
```

JSON String is in the form

```
{"station_list":{"35":{"www":"cbsplayer.streamtheworld.com\/?CALLSIGN=KRTHFM","sid":"6386","streams":{"test_up":0,"stream_bitrate":"2","stream_format_string":".MP3\/.M3U Playlist","now_playing":"","stream_bitrate_string":"32 kbps","stream_format":"9","stream_url":"http:\/\/cbsplayer.streamtheworld.com\/?CALLSIGN=KRTHFM"},"number":35,"name":"CBS Radio KRTHFM - Classic Hits"},"36":{"www":"cbsplayer.streamtheworld.com\/?CALLSIGN=KXKLFM","sid":"6399","streams":{"test_up":0,"stream_bitrate":"2","stream_format_string":".MP3\/.M3U Playlist","now_playing":"","stream_bitrate_string":"32 kbps","stream_format":"9","stream_url":"http:\/\/cbsplayer.streamtheworld.com\/?CALLSIGN=KXKLFM"},"number":36,"name":"CBS Radio KXKLFM - Classic Hits"},"159":{"www":"www.pointbreakfm.moonfruit.com","sid":"37070","streams":{"test_up":0,"stream_bitrate":"5","stream_format_string":"Shoutcast (AAC+)","now_playing":"","stream_bitrate_string":"128 kbps","stream_format":"20","stream_url":"http:\/\/open.wavepanel.net\/shoutcast\/listen\/f77e2312b0e73a12585975a65de4d236bfce83e2\/1\/ram"},"number":159,"name":"Pointbreak FM"},"33":{"www":"cbsplayer.streamtheworld.com\/?CALLSIGN=KOOLFM","sid":"6379","streams":{"test_up":0,"stream_bitrate":"2","stream_format_string":".MP3\/.M3U Playlist","now_playing":"","stream_bitrate_string":"32 kbps","stream_format":"9","stream_url":"http:\/\/cbsplayer.streamtheworld.com\/?CALLSIGN=KOOLFM"},"number":33,"name":"CBS Radio KOOLFM - Classic Hits"},"158":{"www":"radio.xynez.com\/sg\/yes933\/","sid":"35906","streams":{"test_up":0,"stream_bitrate":"1","stream_format_string":"Windows Media","now_playing":"","stream_bitrate_string":"24 kbps","stream_format":"8","stream_url":"http:\/\/radio.xynez.com\/sg\/yes933\/play.asx"},"number":158,"name":"YES 933 FM ???????? Your Entertainment Station"},"34":{"www":"cbsplayer.streamtheworld.com\/?CALLSIGN=KQJKFM","sid":"6381","streams":{"test_up":0,"stream_bitrate":"2","stream_format_string":".MP3\/.M3U Playlist","now_playing":"","stream_bitrate_string":"32 kbps","stream_format":"9","stream_url":"http:\/\/cbsplayer.streamtheworld.com\/?CALLSIGN=KQJKFM"},"number":34,"name":"CBS Radio KQJKFM - Jack"},"157":{"www":"radiomobiel.playtheradio.com\/","sid":"35853","streams":{"test_up":0,"stream_bitrate":"0","stream_format_string":"Shoutcast","now_playing":"","stream_bitrate_string":null,"stream_format":"1","stream_url":"http:\/\/listen.radionomy.com\/radiomobiel.m3u"},"number":157,"name":"Radio Mobiel"},"39":{"www":"cbsplayer.streamtheworld.com\/?CALLSIGN=WCBSFM","sid":"6419","streams":{"test_up":0,"stream_bitrate":"2","stream_format_string":".MP3\/.M3U Playlist","now_playing":"","stream_bitrate_string":"32 kbps","stream_format":"9","stream_url":"http:\/\/cbsplayer.streamtheworld.com\/?CALLSIGN=WCBSFM"},"number":39,"name":"CBS Radio WCBSFM - Jack"},"156":{"www":"www.wonderlandradio.nl","sid":"35729","streams":{"test_up":0,"stream_bitrate":"5","stream_format_string":"Shoutcast","now_playing":"","stream_bitrate_string":"128 kbps","stream_format":"1","stream_url":"http:\/\/www.server-07.stream-server.nl:8388"},"number":156,"name":"wonderlandradio"},"155":{"www":"kfm.listen2myradio.com","sid":"35449","streams":{"test_up":0,"stream_bitrate":"4","stream_format_string":"Shoutcast","now_playing":"","stream_bitrate_string":"96 kbps","stream_format":"1","stream_url":"http:\/\/kfm.listen2myradio.com"},"number":155,"name":"kfmuae decades of hits"},"37":{"www":"cbsplayer.streamtheworld.com\/?CALLSIGN=KZJKFM","sid":"6408","streams":{"test_up":0,"stream_bitrate":"2","stream_format_string":".MP3\/.M3U Playlist","now_playing":"","stream_bitrate_string":"32 kbps","stream_format":"9","stream_url":"http:\/\/cbsplayer.streamtheworld.com\/?CALLSIGN=KZJKFM"},"number":37,"name":"CBS Radio KZJKFM - Jack"},"154":{"www":"ituneshits.listen2myradio.com","sid":"35399","streams":{"test_up":0,"stream_bitrate":"4","stream_format_string":"Shoutcast","now_playing":"","stream_bitrate_string":"96 kbps","stream_format":"1","stream_url":"ituneshits.listen2myradio.com"},"number":1
```

Answer (score 1):

try to parse json String as to get `stream_url` from it :

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(uri.toString());

JSONObject jsonstation_list=json.getJSONObject("station_list");

ArrayList<String> urlarray=new ArrayList<String>();

// get all names from json object
JSONArray jsonarray_names=jsonstation_list.names();
 for(int i=0;i<jsonarray_names.length();i++){
    // get jsonobjects
    JSONObject jsonone=jsonstation_list.getJSONObject(
                                              jsonarray_names.getString(i));

    // get streams
    JSONObject jsonstreams=jsonone.getJSONObject("streams");
    // get stream_url 
    urlarray.add(jsonstreams.getString("stream_url"));
  }

}
```

Comment: he doesn't have a `JSONArray` in his given `JSON` String , but it should be , by converting `station_list` from `JSONObject` to `JSONArray`

Comment: @Houcine : actually  station_list JSONObject contain only JSONObjects . that's why i have created an JSON array to get all JSONObject names from  station_list and then we can easy iterate through all objects to get stream_url

Comment: yes i'm agree with you :) , but you should add in your answer that the `station_list` should be a `JSONArray` in order to change it in his code

Comment: @Houcine : im not getting u. is there any issue in my answer?

Comment: no , your answer is correct only if the station_list is a JSONArray, but in the question : he mentionned that the station_list is a `JSONObject`  ( `{"station_list":{"35":{"www":"cbsplayer....)` , i told you to add to your answer that the attribute `"station_list"` should be a JSONArray  like this : `{"station_list":["35":{"www":"cbsplayer.....]`

Comment: @Houcine : as i see in doc [JSONObject.names()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#names%28%29) return an JsonArray of containing the string names in this JSONObject

Comment: ah ok +1 , so it's OK , the method names() return a `JSONArray`